# Get battery level after every 1% accuracy in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, batterylevel, batterymanager

I want to get the change in battery level after 1% accuracy in my iPhone. I want to do this in swift.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 8+ use

`UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryLevel`